# Python Django : ImportError: No module named bootstrap3

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 , django.VERSION (1, 7, 7, 'final', 0) .
django-bootstrap3 5.3.1 is installed using pip.
Still I am getting error `ImportError: No module named bootstrap3`

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-246:/opt$ python peace/src/manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peace/src/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bootstrap3
```

I am able to import this module in python console.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-246:/opt$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import  bootstrap3
>>> dir( bootstrap3)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
>>> print  bootstrap3.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bootstrap3']
>>>
```

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: @VaibhavMule , yes Amazon ec2

Comment: Check that in django env like python manage.py shell and import bootstrap3

Comment: if then you have to activate virtual-environment and then start the server

Comment: You have to `source /opt/<myenv>/bin/activate` replace <myenv> with virtualenv you have created and you can know that by doing `ls` in `/opt/`

Answer (score 2):

You can install virtualenv using `pip install virtualenv`

or

Install virtualenv from source

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ python virtualenv.py env
```

Then activate virtualenv using below command

```
source env/bin/activate
```